# ‘Feature detecting’ required compile flags in Make (liconv on Mac)

Tags: linker, makefile, conditional-compilation

Ubuntu has `libiconv` built-in to it’s standard c library and does not require it in `LDFLAGS`. OS X does not have it built-in and requires the flag to be set.

My current approach is using `ifeq` in my Makefile to conditionally set `LDFLAG += -liconv` when on OS X.

I am wondering if there is a better approach? I am heavily influenced by the feature-detection mindset of web development and hope I can use a similar approach to detect whether the flag is required on the current system or not.

Answer (score 0):

For manually written makefiles individually setting the contents of the `LDFLAGS` and friends is an acceptable way of doing it. This may be simpler if there is only couple of features needed.

If you want to generically detect the feature one route to go would be to use a makefile generator like *CMake* or *Automake*.

The final option would be to manually perform the runtime checks that Automake does. That is to have a sample file that you compile, link with one of the options and see if it works. If it doesn't try the next and so on. This way you are testing what flags are required for each feature. Automake does this onece, when the project is `./configure`d but you could do it every time `make` is run or whenever is good for your build setup.